# External Jquery Script not working

Tags: joomla-3.x, jquery

External Jquery script not working in Joomla template. Below I pasted script for reference. Any help greatly appreciated

```
function ShowLayer() {
        var layer = $(this).attr("layer-id");
        if (!$("#" + layer).is(":visible")) {
            var zindex = $("#" + layer).css("z-index");
            $("#" + layer).removeClass("zIndex");
            $("#" + layer).css("z-index", zindex + 1);
            //$("#" + layer).slideIn();
            SlideIn($("#" + layer));
        }
    }
    function SlideIn(current) {
        var scope = $('.outer');
        current.css("left", $(scope).width());
        current.show();
        current.animate({ left: 0 }, 700, "linear", function () {               
        });
    }
    function SlideOut(current) {
        var scope = $('.outer');
        current.animate({ left: $(scope).width() }, 700, "linear", function () {
            current.css("z-index", "")
            current.addClass("zIndex");  
            current.hide();
        });
    }
    function CloseLayer() {
        var layer = $(this).attr("layer-id");               
        SlideOut($("#" + layer));
    }
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.show-layer').click(ShowLayer);
        $('.close-layer').click(CloseLayer);
        $('.scrollerview').css("opacity", "0");
        $(window).scroll(function () {
            $('.scrollerview').each(function (i) {
                var factor = -250;
                if ($(this).hasClass("PckHdOtr")) {
                    factor = 250;
                }
                var bottom_of_object = $(this).offset().top + $(this).outerHeight();
                var bottom_of_window = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() - factor;
                if (bottom_of_window > bottom_of_object) {
                    $(this).animate({ 'opacity': '1' }, 900);
                    if ($(this).hasClass("PckHdOtr")) {
                        $('.outer').animate({ 'opacity': '1' }, 900);
                    }
                }
            });

        });
    });
```

Comment: It would help if you could provide any console log errors and  tell us where you're adding the code

Comment: I am getting console log error as "Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function" and I am adding this in <head> section

Comment: Make sure you add this code at the bottom of the head section, right above the `</head>`. Please also look at @fruppel's answer

Comment: I edited my answer

Answer (score 6):

You are probably running into conflict problems, since both jQuery and the mootools library use the '$' char as shortcut.

There are multiple ways to deal with that problem. You have to find out which method works best for you. Not all of these may apply to your template.

**A) Replace all '$' characters with 'jQuery' as $ is a shortcut for jQuery**

**B) Add this line right before your code**

```
var $ = jQuery.noConflict();
```

After that you can use $ in your script

**C) Wrap your whole code into the jQuery wrapper function and use $ as scope, like**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    // All of your code, including your functions
});
```

or the more concise syntax for the code above:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    // Your code
});
```

> You also have to make sure that you add this code **after** you
>   include the jQuery library.

You can read more about conflicts with other libraries here: http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/avoid-conflicts-other-libraries/

Comment: Sorry, it's not working.

Comment: I see the problem and updated my answer

Comment: glad to hear that. could you accept my answer then?